# PHP randomly deletes session

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-timeout, sessionid

On our PHP site (PHP 5.4.30), users are being logged out due to losing their PHP Session.

## How to know the session is lost

```
   session_start();

   if (isset($_SESSION['version']) and file_exists($_SESSION['version'] . '/go.php')) {
        require $_SESSION['version'] . '/go.php';
   }
   else {
        session_destroy();
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        header("Location: 401.php");
   }
```

## Some investigations

- The majority of users use Google Chrome.
- There are no 404 issues (like favicons).
- No cross-domain files are referenced.
- No pages are likelier than others to lose sessions. Log in again, and the action you were performing in the system works again.
- No PHP configuration is ever modified at runtime.
- There is nothing funny going on in .htaccess (just protection and certain rewrites).
- This only happens in the live environment (CentOS 5.1.1), not on dev machines.
- There are no other blatant problems AFAIK, such as disk full or write errors to /tmp.

## php.ini

[image: php.ini content]

## /tmp

I have checked /tmp on the server and the session file is still there after being logged out

```
me@example.com [/tmp]# dir -l sess_abcdefb967fc79364a5a773e0157d663
-rw------- 1 si si 565 Apr  3 09:51 sess_abcdefb967fc79364a5a773e0157d663
```

## Headers

A typical pageview results in a header like:

```
General
Remote Address:123.123.171.111:443  
Request URL:https://example.com/mx/TypicalPage  
Request Method:GET  
Status Code:200 OK  

Response Headers 
Cache-Control:private  
Connection:Keep-Alive  
Content-Length:6716  
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8  
Date:Fri, 03 Apr 2015 20:43:06 GMT  
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT  
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100  
Pragma:no-cache  
Server:Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5   mod_bwlimited/1.4 PHP/5.4.30  
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.30  

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch  
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,pt-BR;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2  
Connection:keep-alive  
Cookie:PHPSESSID=1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef  
Host:simplement.com.br  
Referer:https://example.com/mx/PreviousPage  
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2356.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: what's the expiry policy you're using (are you using `session_cache_limiter()` before `session_start()` for instance?), and what are the session headers that you see coming back in the browser/curl/etc when you connect to your server on an initiated session?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I'm not using session_cache_limiter() anywhere. My expiry policy is supposed to be 86400 seconds (1 day), but sessions expire (randomly) way before that. What do you mean by session headers? I see the $_SESSION variables when I dump them, and I see the cooky with the session ID, is that what you asked?

Comment: the headers your server sends to the browser. Fire up Chrome, open its devtools, select the network tab, reload, and then check what the page's header information gives you. That would be good information to add to the excellent information already in your question.

Comment: Thanks, the headers are a great resource. I've updated the question, hth!

Comment: Nice. PHP sessions are based on passing the session identifier to the server either via GET, POST or cookies, so in this case the identifier seems to be in a cookie (`Cookie:PHPSESSID=1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef`), if the session is lost this would be because the cookie gets unset. Do you have any code that does cookie management either in PHP or client-side in JS that might be clearing this?

Comment: I rely on PHP setting the session cookie as specified in php.ini - I don't explicitly set nor unset it. Neither should JS - there's a bit of jQuery, but the site is (still) full pageloads. My intuition tells me if it were cookies getting unset in code, the problem would re-appear upon performing the same actions - but I can't force it to happen (yet), I have to wait until it occurs.

Comment: can you narrow this down to "just Chrome", or are other browsers also affected that you know of? (if you have reliable STR, what happens in the headers from a sessioned user when their session drops?)

Comment: I've checked the logs (I started logging sessionIDs only yesterday, so there's not much data yet), but: After such "losses", the sessionID gets regenerated! The user logs in (there's only one way to get authenticated) and gets assigned the session ID he had before. That can't be right! All examples are Chrome (perhaps due to user base), but I've read that perhaps prefetching is to blame. Have you got any idea?

Comment: hmm, is the login system tied into the session manager in any way? (own code, or not-my-code package that might be fiddling with $_SESSION based on user credentials?)

Comment: Have you had any luck fixing this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately not :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my new server. It's a common server problem and might be because of a resource shortage.

The problem in my code appeared when trying to redirect user using:

```
header('Location: ...');
```

It's something likely the PHP has not finished writing session to handler (mine was files) and `header` function redirects page.

I have fixed the problem with calling `session_regenerate_id` and `session_write_close` functions before redirecting the user.

```
session_regenerate_id();
session_write_close();

header('Location: ...');
```